# How to display only a part of a .txt file in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
337  PL  Lubochnia  51.60794  20.05391
338  PL  Lubomierz  49.60854  20.20214
339  PL  Lubomino  54.06684  20.23956
340  PL  \u0141askarzew  51.78993  21.59122
341  PL  Lubycza Kr\u00F3lewska  50.34102  23.51941
342  PL  \u0141uk\u00F3w  51.929  22.37956
```

Every line of the file contains an ordinal number, country tag, city name in Unicode (some of the names are composed of two words) and coordinates. I need to move just the city names to a vector and then display it, but I'm new to coding a basically have no idea how to approach this. So far I only managed to move the whole file into a vector, but nothing more than that :/

```
int main()
{
    fstream file;
    file.open("miasta.txt");

    vector<string> cities;
    string line;

    do
    {
        getline(file,line);
        cities.push_back(line);
    }
    while(line!="");

    cout<<"List of cities:"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<cities.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<cities[i]<<endl;
    }

    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your loop reading the file is wrong. It should be `while (getline(file, line)) { cities.push_back(line); }`

Comment: AS for your problem, once you've read each line you need to parse it. You know there will be two initial fields, and two trailing fields. Everything between them has to be the city name.

Comment: Or is the contents of the file *tab* (`'\t'`) separated? Then you can use that to separate each field. This basically means the file is a [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file, just using a different separator.

Comment: the contents are separated with two spaces and the word of the two-word city names are separated with one space

Answer (score 1):

To get substrings from other string I often use regular expresions.
A regular expression lets you define patterns in a string. Like match
3 digits befor matching a few whitespaces etc.

A short introduction: https://www.aivosto.com/articles/regex.html
You can play around with them on : https://regex101.com/

C++ has support in the standard library from the  header.
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex

Here is an example of how that would look like for your case :

```
// next few lines are platform specific. 
// needed on my machine to get the unicode characters
// in the city names to display correctly.
#ifdef WIN32 
    #include <io.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
#endif 

// standard c++ from here on
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

auto extract_city_name(const std::wstring& line)
{
    // this is the regular expression, it means
    // ^ = beginning of line
    // [0-9]{3} is match characters between 0 and 9 and exactly 3 of them
    // \s+ is match one or more white spaces
    // [A-Z]{2} is match characters between A and Z and exactly 2 of them
    // \s+ is match one or more white spaces
    // (\\w+) is match one or more word characters and put then in a match group  
    //        it is this group that will contain your city name!
    // .*$ is match everything left until the end of the string

    static const std::wregex rx{ L"^[0-9]{3}\\s+[A-Z]{2}\\s+(\\w+).*$" };
    static std::wsmatch match;
    std::wstring city_name;

    // if the line matches the regular expression
    // match will contain data. match[0] is the whole string, match[1] is the 
    // first group (the one that matches the city name)

    if (std::regex_search(line, match, rx))
    {
        city_name = match[1].str();
    }

    // else there is no match and it's an input error
    // for now I return an empty city name assuming all input is ok 
    // not recommended in production code ;)

    return city_name;
}

auto get_city_names(const std::vector<std::wstring>& input)
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> city_names;

    for (const auto& line : input)
    {
        auto city_name = extract_city_name(line);
        city_names.push_back(city_name);
    }

    return city_names;
}

int main()
{
    // simulate input from a file by putting all lines in a vector.
    std::vector<std::wstring> input
    {
        L"337  PL  Lubochnia  51.60794  20.05391",
        L"338  PL  Lubomierz  49.60854  20.20214",
        L"339  PL  Lubomino  54.06684  20.23956",
        L"340  PL  \u0141askarzew  51.78993  21.59122",
        L"341  PL  Lubycza Kr\u00F3lewska  50.34102  23.51941",
        L"342  PL  \u0141uk\u00F3w  51.929  22.37956"
    };

    auto city_names = get_city_names(input);

    // city names has correct content, but
    // output with unicode character in it fails.

#ifdef WIN32
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
#endif

    for (const auto& city_name : city_names)
    {
        std::wcout << city_name << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```